# How to import proto file in another proto file in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, protocol-buffers, proto, grpc-node

I've come across the need to import one file into another, but I can't find a clear explanation of how to do it.

So, I have my index proto file using some message from common.proto. All proto files lie in the same directory.

index.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "common.proto";

package index;
```

common.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package common;

message Void {}
```

And I receive message: " Cannot resolve import 'common.proto' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried to set the `--proto_path` flag?
I tried it in my environment and what I think you are missing is telling Protobuf the location of your files

Here you can find the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions

Comment: @wh4y I think they use this flag under the hood, I use WebStorm as well and I knew I had to set it in the beginning.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

### Try loading all proto files from  a directory instead, using `includeDirs`

An example :

```
app.connectMicroservice({
transport: Transport.GRPC,
options: {
  package: 'sample.user',
  protoPath: '/sample/user/user.proto',
  loader: {
    includeDirs: [join(__dirname, '..', 'protos')], // will load all proto files in the diectory 'protos'
  },
},
});
```